# Difference between embeddedset and linkset?

Tags: relationship, orientdb

I'm using v1.5.1 but will soon upgrade to 1.6.

What is the difference between embeddedset and linkset? Should one be preferred over the other?

I don't really need linkset for my application, but I am wondering about performance and usability (e.g. is querying/modification harder with embeddedset?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the official documentation about relationship: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Concepts#relationships

Comment: I've read this, and while it does answer my first question, I'm still not sure what the use-case is for embedded relationships? Also is there a difference in performance, or should I not worry about that?

Comment: By embedding records you avoid a traversal of link, but the record is bigger. It depends by the use case, with OrientDB you can choose to use embedded (like MongoDB) or link (like Neo4J)